# Electron app isnt saving my input to json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

When the user clicks the save button it is supposed to save the apikey into the JSON file. However, the JSON file is still empty with no data added to it. Any help will be appreciated. (I also get no errors)

```
const apiBox = document.getElementById('apibox');
const saveButton = document.getElementById('saveapi');

saveButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const apiKey = apiBox.value;

    const data = {
        apikey: apiKey
    };

    const jsonStr = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);

    fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../data/data.json'), jsonStr);
});
```

JSON file:

```
{
    "apikey": ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the data to the main process to use the `fs` module. You can use electron's IPC functions in the renderer by exposing them with a preload script.

This would look something like:

###### Main

```js
ipcMain.on('message', (event, message) => {
    fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../data/data.json'), message);
});
```

###### Preload

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron/renderer')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
  writeFile: (data) => ipcRenderer.send('message', data)
})
```

###### Renderer

```js
saveButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const apiKey = apiBox.value;
    const data = { apikey: apiKey };
    const jsonStr = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
    window.electronAPI.writeFile(jsonStr);
});
```

[Electron IPC guide](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc)